# Unwanted item name flattening

Tags: msbuild

I have a task like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
     <Folder Include="d:\Trunk">
        <BranchName>MyBranch</BranchName>
     </Folder>         
     <Folder Include="d:\8.1">
        <BranchName>MyBranch</BranchName>
     </Folder>         
  </ItemGroup>
  <Message Text="BranchName: %(Folder.BranchName), Folder: @(Folder)" />
```

What I am expecting:

```
BranchName: MyBranch, Folder: d:\Trunk
BranchName: MyBranch, Folder: d:\8.1
```

What I've got:

```
BranchName: MyBranch, Folder: d:\Trunk;d:\8.1
```

I know that flattening items identities is a feature of MSBuild. But is it prossible to get rid of this? Flattening items by MetaData value doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that its grouping by metadata value.  If you were to change the value of the second BranchName node to "AnotherBranch" you'd have this output:

```
BranchName: MyBranch, Folder: d:\Trunk
BranchName: AnotherBranch, Folder: d:\8.1
```

You're using grouping by the BranchName, so all items for that branch are grouped together, so lets group by the identity of the Folder and see if that gives us the desired results:

```
<Message Text="Branch: @(Folder->Metadata('BranchName')), Folder: %(Folder.Identity)" />
```

Output:

```
Branch: MyBranch, Folder: d:\Trunk
Branch: MyBranch, Folder: d:\8.1
```

Edit:

Or you can drop the @ notation and reference the item metadata directly:

```
<Message Text="Branch: %(Folder.BranchName), Folder: %(Folder.Identity)" />
```